# How Can I Create a rule in firestore security rules for each item in my array

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

[I can access a single item with its index like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaqfP.png)

In this example i can access a single item in that array but i want the rule to be not for that single item but for each item in that array.

Comment: DO NOT post links.  Post images if you *have* to, but mostly post formatted TEXT, so others can search the questions and  find similar information.

Also links are EXTREMELY INSECURE, and show no respect for those who post answers - don't make us do all the work.

Comment: Well sorry this was my first post and it automatically generated the link when i pressed on add image :( didnt know how to post a formatted text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking for a solution for some time couldn't find anything and instead of storing the Posts in an array i just created a collection inside the Person document and stored them in there.